# My Android is Freezing after Factory reset

Tags: rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung, factory-reset

I am using a Galaxy Note Lte (SHV-E160S) it was working slowly lately so decided to root it to improved it performance. After rooting i Installed an application called SYSTEM APPS REMOVER which help me remove some unwanted apps on my phone because i am not using them and they keep on using my data. 
After going through this process i decided to Factory Reset. 
Now comes the problem after successfully factory reset it. Went i got to the configuration of language stage the phone keep on freezing and the screen won't respond but the back and menu keys are all working perfectly. 
Guys i just wanted to ask is the anyway i can skip that stage or any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, in order to track down your problem you need to add more information. Most important: which system apps did you remove?

Answer (score 0):

(Just something you can try)
I know what happened to you can be frustrating. It happened to me once when I accidentally uninstalled an android required app. You can try flashing a GApps zip package. That worked for me.